# Guardar como PDF una página web con Selenium y Python

Tags: python, pdf, selenium

El siguiente código abre chrome, luego busca una página y al cabo de unos segundos guarda como pdf dicha página web. El código funciona perfectamente en mi PC, pero en la PC de mi trabajo no funciona, en vez de Guardar como PDF, manda a imprimir con la impresora predeterminada. Hago pruebas con la url que esta en el código pero en realidad yo quiero guardar como pdf un archivo que se genera en una app interna de mi trabajo, y este link termina en .aspx por lo que no puedo usar request o la opción de guardar automáticamente pdf. La solución es darle a imprimir y guardarlo como pdf, cuando este código me salió pensé que ya lo tenia solucionado, por eso mi consulta es: qué puede estar pasando, porque no funciona en la pc de mi trabajo.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import json

# Configuración de las opciones de Chrome
options = Options()
appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestination": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}
prefs = {
    'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState),
    'savefile.default_directory': 'E:\\Descargas'
}

options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')


# Iniciar el driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Abrir la URL
url = "https://siga.regionlambayeque.gob.pe/docs/reportes/rpt712698.pdf"
driver.get(url)

# Esperar 5 segundos
time.sleep(5)

# Ejecutar el script de impresión
driver.execute_script('window.print();')

# Esperar 20 segundos
time.sleep(10)

# Cerrar el driver
driver.quit()

print("-----FIN-----")
```